Multple cPanel accounts for single domain
We have one cpanel account on a vps hosting oursite.com, along with probably 20 subdomains. To avoid overloading the server, I'd like to create a second cpanel account on vps2 to continue adding subdomains for oursite.com. Is there anyway to make this possible? Could I recreate the same oursite.com account on vps2 but only use the DNS from vps1 to avoid conflict? Create subdomain on vps2, but create A-Record on vps1 to point to vps2 ip?

A subdomain is also a domain
Actually, a subdomain can act just like a normal domain.
You don't think of the BBC, in the domain "bbc.co.uk", as a subdomain, but you could argue that it is. So it's just a word, indicating that something is subordinate to something else. Subdomains function just like domains.
So you could create DNS records for a subdomain called "vps2.oursite.com" and treat that as the main domain on your second cPanel account.
You could, of course, also use an existing subdomain, but by creating a new one you can move all the existing subdomains between the two accounts to find the optimal balance.
